# Story about a parasite working its way into a man's brain

Tags: story-identification

I think I read it in the same collection that had "Leningen vs the Ants."

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately,  "[Leiningen Versus the Ants](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leiningen_Versus_the_Ants)" has been in [more than a dozen anthologies](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?581853) ever since it was first published in _Esquire_ magazine in 1938. And that's just in English. Can you remember more details?

Comment: Sorry, no more information than that. thanks for your comment.

Comment: There is a story called [The Man Whose Nose Was Too Big](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?890156) about a spider crawling up a man's nose and dining off his brain. This was in the 13th Pan Book of Horror Stories while Leiningen versus the Ants was in the 2nd Pan Book of Horror Stories. So the two stories weren't in the same book but they are in the same series.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this because I know what the answer is.  It is Boomerang by Oscar Cook, in the 2nd Pan Book of Horror Stories.  It can be read online here http://nightgallery.net/wp-content/uploads/Caterpillar.doc

Comment: @OrganicMarble - But is it sci-fi or fantasy in any way? A quick read would suggest not

Comment: Don't think such critters exist but I;m easy either way.

Comment: Sounds like Horror not Sci-Fi/Fantasy

Comment: Definitely not SF, but could be considered as Horror/Fantasy, couldn't it ?

Comment: It feels like straight horror to me.

Comment: The question I have to ask is...does such a Borneo earwig actually exist or was it invented by the author solely as a horror creation?

Comment: @DannyMcG I'm pretty sure they are fictional. Their behavior as described in the story certainly is

Comment: @Bob even though you appear to have an answer, could you perhaps [edit] in some details about the story? When you read it, in what language, what did the book look like? We [have a list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) that might help jog your memory.

Answer (score 7):

This is [Boomerang](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?889341) by Oscar Cook, in the [2nd Pan Book of Horror Stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?264637) along with *Leiningen Versus the Ants*. It can be read online [here](http://nightgallery.net/wp-content/uploads/Caterpillar.doc).

> “It seems,” he continued, “that in Borneo there is a kind of mammoth
> earwig—a thing almost as fine and gossamer as a spider’s web, as long
> as a good-sized caterpillar, that lives on waxy secretions. These are
> integral parts of some flowers and trees, and lie buried deep in their
> recesses. It is one of the terrors of these particular tropics, for it
> moves and rests so lightly on a human being that one is practically
> unconscious of it, while, like its English relation, it has a decided
> liking for the human ear: on account of man’s carnivorous diet the wax
> in this has a strong and very succulent taste.”

> As Warwick gave me
> those details, he sat upright on the edge of his easy-chair. He spoke
> slowly, emphasizing each point by hitting the palm of his left hand
> with the clenched fist of his right. It was impossible not to see the
> drift and inference of his remarks.

> “You mean——?” I began.

> “Exactly,” he broke in quickly, blowing a cloud of smoke from a fresh
> cigarette which he had nervously lighted. “Exactly. It was a devilish
> idea. To put the giant earwig on Macy’s hair just above the ear.”

> “And then…?” I knew the fatuousness of the ques­tion, but speech
> relieved the growing sense of ticklish horror that was creeping over
> me.

> “Do nothing. But rely on the filthy insect running true to type.
> Once inside Macy’s ear, it was a thousand-to-one chance against it
> ever coming out the same way: it would not be able to turn: to back
> out would be almost an impossibility, and so, feeding as it went, it
> would crawl right across inside his head, with the result that——”